# Using Pandas to develop own correlation python similar to pearson

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, correlation, sklearn-pandas

```
 count          716865                 716873                  716884                 716943  
  0   -0.16029615828413712    -0.07630309240006158    0.11220663712532133    -0.2726775504078691  
  1    -0.6687265363491811     -0.6135022705188075   -0.49097425130988914     -0.736020384028633  
  2    0.06735205699309535     0.07948417451634422    0.09240256047258057     0.0617964313591086  
  3      0.372935701728449     0.44324822316416074     0.5625073287879649     0.3199599294007491  
  4    0.39439310866886124     0.45960496068147993     0.5591549439131621    0.34928093849248304  
  5   -0.08007381002566456   -0.021313801077641505    0.11996141286735541   -0.15572679401876433  
  6    0.20853071107951396     0.26561990841073535     0.3661990387594055    0.15720649076873264  
  7    -0.0488049712326824     0.02909288268076153    0.18643283476719688    -0.1438092892727158  
  8   0.017648470149950992     0.10136455179350337     0.2722686729095633   -0.07928001803992157  
  9     0.4693208827819954      0.6601182040950377                    1.0     0.2858790498612906  
 10    0.07597883305423633      0.0720868097090368    0.06089458880790768    0.08522329510499728
```

I want to manipulate this normalized dataframe to do something similar to the .corr method python has built in but want to modify it. I want to create my own method for correlation and build a heatmap which I know how to do.
My end result is a dataframe which will be NxN with 0 or 1 values that meets criterias below. In the table I show above it will be 4x4.

The following steps are the criteria for my correlation method:

1. Loop through each column as the reference and subtract all the other columns from it.
2. As we loop I also want to disregard absolute values if both the reference and the correlating column have normalized values of less than 0.2.
3. For the remaining, if the difference values are less than 10 percent, it means the correlations is good and I start building it with 1 for positive correlation and 0 if any of the difference of the count values is greater than 10%.

all the diagonals will have a 1 for good correlation to each other and the other cells will have either 0 or 1.

The following is what I have but when I drop the deadband values, it does not catch all for some reason.
subdf = []
deadband = 0.2

```
for i in range(len(df2_norm.columns)):
     # First, let's drop non-zero above deadband values in each row
     df2_norm_drop = df2_norm.drop(df2_norm[(df2_norm.abs().iloc[:,i] < deadband) & \
                 (df2_norm.abs().iloc[:,i] > 0)].index)
     # Take difference of first detail element normalized value to chart allowable
     # normalized value
     subdf.append(pd.DataFrame(df2_norm.subtract(df2_norm.iloc[:,i], axis =0)))
```

I know it looks a lot but would really appreciate any help. Thank you!